# Multitasking latency and throughput

Tags: java, multithreading, multiprocessing, multitasking

I have been doing some experimentation around multi-threading and multi-tasking and I have a few questions.

1) Consider a machine with just one CPU core/processor. Running multiple threads *parallely* is achieved by time slicing (each thread is given a few milliseconds to run on the CPU) and if one thread is blocked on I/O, the others can run, thus giving an impression of doing multiple things concurrently.

Consider the same single processor CPU and say there are two threads, both of which is CPU intensive and does no I/O.
Each takes 5 seconds to complete its operation. Running it sequentially will take obviously 10 secs.

> Will running it parallely (using executor service) also take 10 seconds since the threads are CPU intensive only? (given that there is only one CPU core)

2) On a machine with four cores, I have a task that will take 5 seconds to complete when run independently. I wanted to run a couple of them in parallel as separate *processes* using Java's [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (I don't want to run as parallel threads as the object that they share is not thread safe and cost of synchronization is too much).
I expected it to complete around 5 seconds.

> Starting two parallel process did not yield much improvement as they still took around 9 seconds to complete. Why is that? (the task is both CPU intensive and consumes significant memory). 
>   Note: As I start three or four processes, the latency is more and more affected (worse or equivalent to running them in sequence).

**EDIT**

My intention/ question is more around why the performance is not improved when using processes rather than whether I should use multiple threads/process for my second question.
For question 2, (for the sake of discussion) you can simple imagine the task like this: (Although the numbers mentioned in the question above is not from the below snippet)

```
String s;
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
 s += i; //consumes a lot of memory
}

long result = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  for (double i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) { //Lot of CPU
    result += i;
   }
}
```

Comment: tell us more about "the object that they share" and precisely how they share it.

Comment: @MikeNakis It is a static object holding a bunch of state. So I want to create separate processes and let each work in their own context/space.

Comment: @MikeNakis Please see the updated question with code snippets.

Comment: It will be very helpful to see the full code including how you were calculating the execution time.

Answer (score 2):

> Will running it parallely (using executor service) also take 10
>   seconds since the threads are CPU intensive only? (given that there is
>   only one CPU core)

In principle, no.  By running them in parallel, you're bound to waste some time in context-switching, so theoretically, they'll take more than 10s.  In practice, the difference will hardly be detectable, because the additional load from your two processes (or threads) may not turn up contention for CPU enough for any noticeable increase of losses in switching.

> Starting two parallel process did not yield much improvement as they
>   still took around 9 seconds to complete. Why is that? (the task is
>   both CPU intensive and consumes significant memory). Note: As I start
>   three or four processes, the latency is more and more affected (worse
>   or equivalent to running them in sequence).

Your experiment is contaminated by the overhead of starting two or more processes instead of just one, so it's practically useless to try and draw any conclusions here (unless you took special care to measure exactly the calculation portion of the task.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Answer to your 1st question:
```

The process/thread burst diagram is shown below

> I/O ==> CPU ==> I/O ===>  CPU ==>...... I/O..... ==> CPU == > I/o

It's pretty obvious that they will start and end up with an I/o burts And the multiprocessing/threading on a single processor is achieved only in time multiplexed manner, like you said.

Coming to your question:
Here both of your jobs/threads are CPu bound jobs and doesn't contain any any internal I/O(refer to flow referred above) operation. Therefore, It might take the same time as that of a sequential setup. In case you have a lot of threads running the same way , which donot have any internal I/o bound operations may take more time than the sequential access because then a lot of time is spent in context switching.

because of such scenarios LongTerm Schedulers are designed and programmed to put a proper mix of I/o bound and Cpu bound jobs in the ready queue.

Answer (score 0):

How many operations are you running? The performance might not improve by much because of the overhead in communication. Because everything has a cost, the amount of time required to coordinate parallel tasks may have dominated the time spent on actually solving the problem, making it no longer favorable to parallelize your code.

Comment: What do you mean by coordination? They are just independent jobs that does something. They don't share any Java objects. The only resource they share are the CPU and memory

Comment: Theoretically, your program shouldn't accrue any overhead because the tasks are functioning independently from each other and no communication is required. However, in practice, this isn't the case. 

[Overhead](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#DesignCommunications) can be introduced in many ways: invoking a function, data transferring, latency, bandwidth, etc.

In your case, I assume it's mainly from data travelling from memory to the CPU.